# Get properties of a type including base class properties using Mono Cecil

Tags: c#, mono.cecil

Is there a direct way to get *all* the properties of a type using Mono Cecil, including those only defined in base classes? (in C# preferably)

If the base class is defined in a different assembly, is the other assembly resolved as needed?

A few hours later & employing a thousand monkeys typing randomly in a thousand instances of Visual Studio, I came up with the following, which appears to work - am I missing something?

```
public static List<PropertyDefinition> PropertiesFlattened(this TypeDefinition asmType)
{
    //get properties on main type:
    List<PropertyDefinition> props = new List<PropertyDefinition>(from PropertyDefinition property in asmType.Properties select property);

    //get properties of base types:
    if (asmType.BaseType != null && asmType.BaseType.FullName != "System.Object")
    {
        TypeDefinition baseType = asmType.BaseType.Resolve();

        //recursive call:
        if (baseType != null)
            props.AddRange(baseType.PropertiesFlattened());
    }

    return props;
}
```

Comment: There is no "direct" way. What you came with is the common way, as Mono Cecil is just a thin layer over MSIL.